# Line of Best Fit Optimization Problem (Stewart's Early Transcendentals, 14.7, #55)

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]

I know posting pictures is kind of frowned upon here, but I didn't want to type the whole problem out, diagram and all.

I'm feeling pretty lost on this one. We've been learning about absolute minima and maxima of functions of two variables in class, but I don't know what the variables are here. We need to find an $m$ and $b$ I guess, but where to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are the unknown slope $m$ and the unknown $y$-intercept.  Your sum-of-squares error is the following:

$$SSE(m, b)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (mx_{i}+b - y_{i})^{2}$$

where you observed the $n$ values $(x_{i}, y_{i})$.  I wrote SSE as a function of $m$ and $b$ to emphasize that those are your variables... any choice of those values leads to some SSE.  This makes all the $x_{i}$'s and $y_{i}$'s constants.  Think of the $mx_{i}+b$ as the "predictor" of $y_{i}$ and $mx_{i}+b - y_{i}$ as how far the predictor is off.  (Squared of course so that the error becomes positive but the function is still differentiable--the reason people shy away from using absolute value.)

Comment: The $SSE(m, b)$ is what you want to minimize.  You want to show that the $(m,b)$ value that makes the derivative zero (both partial derivatives) will simultaneously solve those two equations.

Answer (score 0):

You've been finding absolute mins and max's for functions of two variables.  Here, we want to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$.

Set $f(m,b)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$  Then $f(m,b)=\sum_{i=1}^n [y_i-(mx_i+b)]^2$.  You have a theorem that says if $f$ has a local max or min at a point and the first-order partial derivatives exist there, then those partials equal zero.

Take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $b$ and set it equal to zero.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^n 2(y_i -mx_i-b )(-1)=0$.  Expand this and you will see it is the first equation they are wanting you to show holds for the best fit line.

Take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $m$ and set it equal to zero.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^n 2(y_i -mx_i-b )(-x_i)=0$.  Expand this and you will see it is the second equation they are wanting you to show holds for the best fit line.